# Internet explorer 8 - https

Tags: iis, browser, https

I have this this kind of problem that get me stuck for a day. I have an ***IIS server***. And when i access it from other network using **IE8** or **chrome** it work perfectly.

But when i access it from different network using chrome still it works fine. but when i used **IE8** it says webpage cannot display. any help will be much appreciate.

I'd stuck here so long. I tried all suggestions on the web but it didn't help me. I hope you can help me figure this out.

Comment: What's the message?

Comment: Can you test your server with ssllabs.com ?

Comment: i'd tested it via ssllabs the overall rating was A.
Certificate 100
Protocol Support 95
Key Exchange 85
Cipher Strength 85

and it works fine. base on my observation it can't be accessible using IE with xp OS